# KoaJs can only stream one connection at once

Tags: node.js, koa, co

I'm trying to do something bigpipe with koajs.

```
app.use(function* () {
    this.type = 'html';
    this.body = myPage.stream() // returns a readable
})
```

inside the myPage

```
myPage.prototype.stream = function() {
    var readable = new stream.Readable();
    readable._read = function() {};
    co(myRender(readable.push.bind(readable))).catch(errorHandler)
    return readable;
});
```

Then the render will do the rendering stuff (async);

However, it works smoothly until I tried to open multi tabs on my browser.

It will not render other pages until one is done (i had a setTimeout to simulate async stuff in the rendere).

Is there anyway to stream multiple connections simultaneously? Like it does with normal requests (not bigpipe) ?

Comment: I can't help you much, but definitely you should add context to your code, since koa uses `ctx` for every request, and that way every request would create a different stream